# Better to use a RANGE RIGHT or RANGE LEFT Partition Scheme

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I'd like to know if it is better to use a RANGE RIGHT partition scheme or a RANGE LEFT partition scheme?

Is one of these options by default a better choice, or is it heavily dependent on the actual data?

Once you've already used a RANGE LEFT, how difficult is it to switch to a RANGE RIGHT? Or is it easier to just add in splits in the current scheme?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a question of better or worse, but business requirements will drive that choice. For instance, we're talking about whether or not you want your defined boundary values to live in one partition or the next.

An example of a boundary value of '9/12/2013', would you want that boundary valued data to live in *partition x* (range left) or *partition x + 1* (range right)?  This will especially come into play when you're thinking about things like individual partition management, as well as partition switching for purposes such as archiving.